# Is there any authorised private or public framework for ios to read/get the text from screenshots?

Tags: ios, xcode, object

Is there any possibility to read/get the text from the screenshots taken on iPhone?? If yes, how can we achieve this?

Comment: iOS does not have an API for OCR, but there are multiple solutions out there to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it out following links.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios
https://www.abbyy.com/mobile-ocr/iphone-ocr/

Comment: Thanks Jayesh :).. Hope it helps my requirement